# SC to LC converter - performance penalty?

Tags: fiber

I'm maintaining a cross connect and using a SC to LC adapter to patch the LC into my equipment.

Was wondering if anyone has a clue on what's the penalty of using the converter in oppose to installing a LC patch directly.

Would appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The light levels will decrease (0.3 -  0.5)dBm in best case scenario. Why aren't you using direct SC to LC patch cord without the adapter?

Comment: Data center patch panel is utilized with SC connector, and I'm using SC to LC to patch a transceiver into a fiber switch.

Comment: since i'm not that familiar with Fiber, how is dBm converted into microseconds / nanoseconds?

Comment: So the XC is Client -> Patch panel -> Main trace -> Patch panel -> your equipment. If so, you can measure the light level on the other side's transceiver (Client TX). Then you can measure on your side's transceiver (Your RX). This way you can calculate the attenuation from the patch cords and the converter/s. 

PS the datacenter engineers should be instructed to measure every single one cross-connect, to make sure that the service will have the quality the customers expect.

Comment: You can not turn dBm to us or ns. You can measure the light level, coming from the patch cord to compare it with your SFP (optical transceiver)
If you're using cisco device type [show interface X/X transceiver details] to see min / max values for the light level (dBm / mW)